# Create querystring list with IpagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

in the controller i have:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3}; 
ViewBag.List = numbers;
```

then in the view i do this:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, 
page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, new[] = ViewBag.List  }))
```

I want it the `pagedlistpager` to produce a link like this:

`/?numbers=1&numbers=2&numbers=3`

in other words how would i just

```
Url.Action("index", new { [] numbers = Viewbag.List})
```

something like that im not sure how to deal with syntax.

obviously that code is wrong because i cant have [] in an anonymous type but maybe somebody can help me out with something similar or a solution to produce that link from viewbag.

IM USING ASP.net MVC 4.

Comment: You want the same querystring variable to have three different values? Are you sure that's what you're after?

Comment: its an array of querystrings that i use.

Comment: So if you interrogated the querystring variable `numbers`, what are you expecting the value to be, considering you've specified it three times?

Comment: in jquery i get the ?numbers=1&numbers=2&numbers=3 and put them in a var numbers = [].So numbers[1] would be 2.I want to create that link with Url.action method.

Comment: Ok, the reason I ask is different frameworks have different ways of interpreting duplicate querystring variables, so I would suggest you avoid them if possible.

Comment: sorry i thought the tags would say what im using..im using asp.net mvc 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit ugly but might work:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model, 
    page => 
        Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }) + 
        "&" + 
        string.Join(
            "&", 
            ((int[])ViewBag.List).Select(x => "numbers=" + Url.Encode(x.ToString()))
        )
)
```

As an alternative to writing this soup, you could write  custom HTML helper that will take care of that.